# DocuSign formatting field value

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to convert amount entered in DocuSign Text Field into an accounting format? User enters amount as 1000000.00 i need to show it as $1,000,000.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add an additional formula tab to be near the text field where the number is entered. The formula tab will automatically insert separators.

See screenshot:

[image]

The number of decimal places shown by the formula tab is an attribute that can be changed.

### How to add the formula tab shown above

1. You need to know the `Data Label` value for the input tab that holds the original number. For this example, I set the `Data Label` of the input tab to be **numbersOnly**
2. Next, create a formula tab and set its formula to be [*Data label of the input tab*]. For my example, I set it to **[numbersOnly]** . See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi Larry,  Can you please show me what you have configured for formula?

Comment: @KumarvijayWalikar -- I have updated my answer. Please remembert o check this answer if it is the best one for your question.

Comment: We can't have the "$" appended to the amount right?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can certainly put a $ in the document next to the field. You may also be able to combine formula fields. Try it.... (And thank you for the check!)